# Dictionary(TKey, TValue) GetHashCode and Equals - How do they work?

Tags: c#

You would think that if two dictionaries contained the same keys and values they would return the same hash code and be equal right? but they don't - what am i doing wrong? or how do I compare dictionaries in this way?

Thanks. Code sameple below

/In this case I also want to test the order is the same/equal.

```
     SortedDictionary<int,string> sd1 = new SortedDictionary<int,string>();
        sd1.Add(1,"one");
        sd1.Add(2, "two");
        sd1.Add(5, "five");
        int sd1Hash = sd1.GetHashCode();

        SortedDictionary<int, string> sd2 = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();
        sd2.Add(1, "one");
        sd2.Add(2, "two");
        sd2.Add(5, "five");
        int sd2Hash = sd2.GetHashCode();

        //This is false
        bool areEqual = sd1.Equals(sd2);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to test that the collections are equal, including their ordering:

```
bool areEqual = sd1.SequenceEqual(sd2);
```

If you wanted to treat the collections as unordered sets:

```
bool areEqual =
    (sd1.Count == sd2.Count) && (sd1.Intersect(sd2).Count() == sd1.Count);
```

*(`SequenceEqual` and `Intersect` can also take an `IEqualityComparer` parameter, if required.)*

As several other answers have stated, `SortedDictionary` doesn't override the default implementations of `Equals` or `GetHashCode`. The default implementation of `Equals` will use reference equality and return `false` because you're comparing two separate objects.

Comment: It took me quite a while to find out that this method is not available in .NET 2.0. Do you know any alternative for .NET 2.0 ?

Comment: You'll have to implement your own IEqualityComparer<SortedDictionary<int, string>> that looks at the contents of the dictionaries to determine the hashcode and equality instead

Comment: @Aamir, As far as I'm aware there's no built-in alternative for .NET2, although it's not difficult to write your own method that iterates through both collections simultaneously and compares each item in turn (which is exactly what the SequenceEqual method does).

Answer (score 0):

> You would think that if two dictionaries contained the same keys and values they would return the same hash code and be equal right?

No, this is not how the Equals and GetHashcode methods are implemented. They are not overriden, so the is the default System.Object implementation, which just compares references.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out MSDN for this issue:

The default implementation of Equals supports reference equality for reference types, and bitwise equality for value types. Reference equality means the object references that are compared refer to the same object. Bitwise equality means the objects that are compared have the same binary representation.

So, since the SortedDictionary contains references, they will be compared. and those are obviously different.

You can find more info on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx